# Angular 7 - Change value of received data from database

Tags: angular, typescript, api

In app.component.ts I receive data via API:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

 constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
 items: Object;
  getApi(){
   return this.http.get("https://reqres.in/api/user");
  }
ngOnInit(){
  this.getApi().subscribe( data => {
    this.items = data
    console.log(this.items)
  })
 }
}
```

In my app.component.html I output that data:

```
<ul *ngIf="items">
   <li *ngFor="let item of items.data">
      {{ item.id }} {{ item.name }} {{ item.year }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

My question is, whether you can change the id with a string connected to the integer of the id.
For example id = 1 => 1 means string "one" , id = 2 => means string "two".

Sadly I do no know how to change the value of the received data with a new value.

I hope it is clear what I want to achieve, if not do not hesitate to ask!

I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: You want to change numbers to words?

Comment: @Oen44 Correct, it is just an example for a real project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know all the values you want to map, you could create a dictionary in your component which would take care of the mapping.

```
myMap = {
    1: "one",
    2: "two"
};
```

and then in your HTML

```
<ul *ngIf="items">
   <li *ngFor="let item of items.data">
      {{ myMap[item.id] }} {{ item.name }} {{ item.year }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it  is the solution I need. I will test it! ~ It worked, thank you!

Comment: Now create hundreds or thousands.

Comment: I agree with Oen44. This is definitely not the way to go if you want to have more than a couple of "known" mappings.

Comment: @Oen44 It is just an example. I do not have the real API, but that is exactly what I needed. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

[number-to-words](https://github.com/marlun78/number-to-words) will do the trick. You won't have to worry about coding names yourself.

```
var converter = require('number-to-words');

ngOnInit(){
  this.getApi().subscribe( data => {
    this.items = data;
    this.items.forEach((item, index) => {
        this.items[index].id = converter.toWords(item.id);
    })
  })
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I keep it in mind in case I will need it but I think mapping is the right way to go because later I will have only 6 cases and for every case there is only one value. I did not have any API so I had to take one on the internet, so the question might be a little confusing. ~ Please forgive me.